# Using Variables In Javascript For Loop

Tags: javascript, variables, checkbox

I have a checkbox contained within a form on my page. When the user clicks a button I need to find out which items in the checkbox have been selected.

I can get this to work with the following code without ay problems.

```
for (i=0; i < Form3.CBox1.length; i++)
  if (Form3.CBox1[i].checked)
   {
   Answer = Answer + Form3.CBox1[i].value + ",";
   } 
alert(Answer);
```

The problem I have is that I call the above function several times on my page and I want to pass in variables instead of hard coding the name of the form and checkbox. Everytime I do this Javascript will not return anything. The variables vCurrForm & vCurrCBox, in the following code, have been set earlier in another function and I have tested to ensure that they are set correctly but I still can't get this piece of code to work.

```
for (i=0; i < vCurrForm.vCurrCBox.length; i++)
  if (vCurrForm.vCurrCBox[i].checked)
   {
   Answer = Answer + vCurrForm.vCurrCBox[i].value + ",";
   } 
alert(Answer);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When working with variables as the keys to an object, you need to use the array syntax (ie. `[]`s), which on its own would give us this (still broken) code:

```
for (i=0; i < vCurrForm[vCurrCBox].length; i++)
{
    if (vCurrForm[vCurrCBox][i].checked)
   {
       Answer = Answer + vCurrForm[vCurrCBox][i].value + ",";
   }
}
alert(Answer);
```

The problem is that `vCurrForm` is still being treated as a regular old variable, even though it's the string name of that variable. Because of this, you need to reference it from its parent; `window`:

```
for (i=0; i < window[vCurrForm][vCurrCBox].length; i++)
{
    if (window[vCurrForm][vCurrCBox][i].checked)
   {
       Answer = Answer + window[vCurrForm][vCurrCBox][i].value + ",";
   }
}
alert(Answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you are declaring and setting these values it is very difficult to ascertain the problem.  It could be related to the type of object the variables are being set to, or their scope. Here are some things to check:

1. Ensure the variable vCurrForm.vCurrCBox is an array.
2. Ensure that vCurrForm and vCurrCBox are declared in a scope that is accessible to the function being called.
3. In this case make sure you are setting vCurrForm to a Form Object and vCurrCBox to an array of checkbox controls.

Looking at the code provided almost makes me think that the variable being referenced is for a single item (Current Checkbox).  Your probably not going to get the results you are looking for in that case.

Something else to consider if it is possible would be to use JQuery to more easily grab the checked boxes and concatenate their values.  In JQuery your code could be done with something like:

```
var Answers = "";
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() { Answers += $(this).val() + ", "; });
```

Comment: Just a quick note on the "makes me think that the variable being referenced is for a single item" - the checkbox is a collection of all the checkboxes sharing a given `name` attribute

Comment: @Joe, in the poster's sample it is difficult to see that.  It is possible to set a variable equal to a collection of objects upstream and manipulate them as you might a control.  Again, without seeing the code that sets the variables we're all just making educated guesses. The data type and how it is being set in this case can make all the difference.

Comment: Sure, it's possible that the variable called `vCurrForm` doesn't map directly to a form and it's possible to that `vCurrCBox` doesn't then map to a collection of CheckBoxes inside it, but it's **probably** safe to assume :) Sure, it's easy to say "But it's still possible!" but really, take a step back and just put the common sense hat on for a moment :P

Answer (score 0):

Or, a better solution is to pass reference to the array that contains elements, instead of matching it with strings. For example:

```
function getAnswers(items) {
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
   {
       if (items[i].checked) {
           Answer = Answer + items[i].value + ",";
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ever so much for all you help. I've seen the error of my ways.

The following worked for me

```
**for (i=0; i < document[vCurrForm][vCurrCBox].length; i++)
    if (document[vCurrForm][vCurrCBox][i].checked)
              {
        Answer = Answer + document[vCurrForm][vCurrCBox][i].value + ",";
        }**
```